# Explain this Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Just started to work with the command prompt, and I need help understanding the following script:

```
n=$(( RANDOM % 100 ))

 if [[ n -eq 42 ]]; then
    echo "Something went wrong"
    >&2 echo "The error was using magic numbers"
    exit 1
 fi

 echo "Everything went according to plan"
```

Can anyone please explain these things to me?

1. `(( RANDOM % 100 ))`
2. `[[ n -eq 42 ]]`
3. `>&2`
4. `exit 1`

Comment: What don't you understand? This is mostly basic shell syntax that should be covered in most tutorials. `>&2` is the only somewhat advanced feature, it means to write the output to stderr (FD 2) instead of stdout.

Comment: Assuming you are using `bash` you'll find the answers here:https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

Comment: `man bash` can explain all of those things to you: arithmetics, control flow and conditions, output redirection, process exit status — all of these keywords can be found there. BTW, I’d use simply `((n == 42))` instead of `[[ n -eq 42 ]]`, because the former is easier to read than the “looks like legacy shell but won’t work in legacy shell” alternative.

Comment: Don't ask several things in a single question. Ask a separate question for each construct you don't understand. BTW, the expression in your script is `$(( RANDOM % 100 ))`, not  `(( RANDOM % 100 ))` (both would be syntactically possible).

Comment: Those are really so basic that you really show a lack of doing your own research (expected by the community) before approaching this forum for assistance.  All those answers are readily available in a basic comprehensive book on bash.  Grab one of those and work thru the exercises from cover to cover then, if there are nuances that you don't understand for more complex forms, then approach the forum with full details of what you tried and what messages you got from those attempts.

Comment: @immaculatecapper. if the below answer did in fact address your needs for tutoring, please click on the checkmark (not the up/down arrows) next to the answer to signify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very basic stuff:

```
$(( RANDOM % 100 ))
```

- `$(( expression ))`

  - mathematical expression evaluation (replacement for `expr ...` )
- `RANDOM % 100`

  - use shell `RANDOM` number generator, value between 1 and 100

```
[[ n -eq 42 ]]
```

- `[[ expression ]]`

  - LOGICAL expression evaluation
- `n -eq 42`

  - compare `n` with 42 and report true if equal

```
>&2
```

- redirect stdout to same stream (display/file/pipe) as stderr

  - proper form would put that at the end of the line, rather than the beginning.

```
exit 1
```

- exit script and provide OS with Return Code value 1 (error)

Comment: Thank you, wjandrea!  I sometimes have trouble with that formatting.